# mysql use while loop in cursor

Tags: mysql, while-loop, cursor

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists insert_person_param;
create procedure insert_person_param()
begin


DECLARE s int DEFAULT 0;
declare p_t_id bigint(20);
declare varmodule int DEFAULT 0;
declare varparam int DEFAULT 0; 
declare m_name varchar(255);

declare pid cursor for select product_id from products;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET s=1;

open pid;
fetch pid into p_t_id;
while s<>1 do

while varmodule<3 do
set m_name=rand_string(2);

while varparam<10 do

insert into person_param (product_id, module_name, param_name, var_type, var_name, var_value, is_activated, compute_value) 
values(p_t_id,concat('模块',m_name),rand_string(3),'int',rand_string(6),'200',1,'ok');
set varparam=varparam+1;
end while;
set varparam=0;
set varmodule=varmodule+1;
end while;
set varmodule=0;

fetch pid into p_t_id;
end while;
close pid;
end $$
```

`rand_string()` and `rand_num()` is a rand function

I want to start a loop in the cursor, I run this sql file inside navicat, but I keep getting an error and I can't see a valid error message. Hope to give me some advice

Comment: Provide **ALL** code needed for to reproduce (tables structures and initial sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, DDL for all used functions, and desired output or final data state) or a link to online fiddle with this code.

Comment: *I run this sql file inside navicat* Use CLI until the code is completely debugged.

Comment: This is my problem so sorry, I have put the correct working code, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `loop` instead of `while`. If the condition check is true for a `While` loop, a whole cycle is executed. Using a `loop` is more flexible as you can choose when to leave. By the way, you have a varialbe named `varparam` which you have not defined. I changed it to a user variable `@varparam` and successfully created the procedure in workbench.

```
create procedure insert_person_param()
begin

DECLARE s int DEFAULT 0;
declare p_t_id bigint(20);
declare varmodule int DEFAULT 0;

declare pid cursor for select product_id from products;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET s=1;

open pid;
lp:loop -- the label for the loop is lp
fetch pid into p_t_id;  -- Unlike like while loop, here we can do the fetch at the begining of the loop. And leave the loop in the upcoming if statement if the NOT FOUND handler is triggered.
if s=1 then -- It should be s=1 when no more to fetch
leave lp; -- leave the loop if NOT FOUND
end if;

while varmodule<3 do
insert into person_param (product_id, module_name, param_name, var_type, var_name, var_value, is_activated, compute_value) 
values(p_t_id,concat('模块','acv'),rand_string(3),'int',rand_string(6),'200',1,'ok');

set varparam=varparam+1; -- WATCH OUT for this varparam, which you have not defined. It raises an error.
end while;
set varparam=0;

end loop lp;
close pid;
end $$
```

Comment: @Akina Thank you very much for your observance. I have changed it to `s=1`.  Usually I  declare a `fin`  variable (which defaults to false) to have a better readability.

Comment: `s` can be either 0 or 1. In this case `if s=1 then` and `if s then` is the same (but 2nd variant is shorter and performs 1 compare less). *Usually I define a fin variable* Opinion-based. I use `done` variable name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have solved my problem. The variable name in the above code was wrong, I corrected it and still used the while loop, and the result was correct. I will remember your answer.